# How to set header not to be transparent using css?

Tags: html, css

I've bulit my own website using Hugo theme.

this is a post:
https://xsong.ltd/zh/model/

The problem is the header will be transparent when float on top of LATEX equation:

[image]

this is css style for header:

```
.header{
top:0px;
position:fixed;
padding:15px 0;
} 

.header{
width:100%;
background:#BEBEBE;
border-bottom:1px solid #ADADAD;
box-shadow:0px 0.12rem 0.25rem 0px #adadad;
}
```

I want deprecate this, e.g., make the navigation header never be transperant to all elements. How to modify my css code?

Comment: try adding ` z-index:10` (or increase z-index in case 10 is not enough).

Comment: `.header { z-index: 1 }` is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `z-index` for this. Apply it to the `.header`. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).